# Generate multiple fields on Wordpress backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm generating a custom field on the Wordpress admin panel. I want to add 2 buttons:
1. Add another
2. Remove field
The add button should generate the same field. I need help coding the javascript that generates the fields.

Here is my code:

```
$html = '';
        $html .= '<div class="pyre_metabox_field">';
            $html .= '<label for="pyre_' . $id . '">';
            $html .= $label;
            $html .= '</label>';
            $html .= '<div class="field">';
                $html .= '<input type="text" id="pyre_' . $id . '" name="pyre_' . $id . '" value="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_' . $id, true) . '" />';
                if($desc) {
                    $html .= '<p>' . $desc . '</p>';
                }
                $html .= '<p style="margin-bottom:15px; padding-top:5px;clear:both;"><a href="#" class="docopy-ads button">Add</a> <a href="#" class="dodelete button">Remove</a></p>';

            $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
```

Comment: Just use Advanced Custom Fields + the Repeater field plugin.  Otherwise this is going to take you a lot more work than you have here.  If you do want to do it yourself though, post what JS you've tried so far so we can help steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried : [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) ?

This plugin is really simple to use, and I'm pretty sure it can do what you're trying to do. It may save you a lot of work :)